# How can I display dynamic value in v-text-field?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm trying to change the UI element from `<v-card-text>` to `<v-text-field>` read-only. While doing so, I face some challenges. This is used to work

```
{{ displayType(campaign.type_name) }}
```

but not they don't. I got error `Errors compiling template:`

```
<v-text-field
    outlined
    small
    value="{{ displayType(campaign.type_name) }}"
    label="Type"
    readonly
></v-text-field>
```

Comment: I assume it's via binding `:value="displayType(campaign.type_name)"`

Comment: `{{ }}` in attributes never worked, this is more of a React thing. `v-bind` is the way to go in Vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```html
<v-text-field
    outlined
    small
    :value="displayType(campaign.type_name)"
    label="Type"
    readonly
></v-text-field>
```